# Spring Boot 3 and Vaadin 24 security filter chain

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I am currently updating an application to Spring Boot 3 and Vaadin 24.
Seems feasible as I spent a lot of time to get to the latest versions in spring boot 2, especially the spring security was challenging. so, from Vaadin 23.3.15 to 24.1.4 and from spring boot 2.7.12 to 3.1.2
So I have by now a working saml sso login, but I am missing something in the filter chain, as things like
FlowClient-d5d5e377.js

?v-r=uidl&v-uiId=0 still give me a 403.

The filter chain before was quite simple:

```
@Bean
SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { 
      http.csrf().disable();
      http.authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize                                                                   
             .antMatchers("/error").permitAll()
             .antMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll()                                                                   
             .anyRequest().authenticated()
              ).saml2Login(saml2 -> {                      
              });                       
                  return http.build();       
         }
```

And I changed that to

```
@Bean
SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http, MvcRequestMatcher.Builder mvc) throws Exception {
http.authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
.requestMatchers(mvc.pattern("/login"), mvc.pattern("/error"), mvc.pattern("/h2console/**")).permitAll()
.anyRequest().authenticated()
).saml2Login(saml2 -> {
});
return http.build();
}
```

But the flow client does not come up as said above. 403 on ?v-r=uidl&v-uiId=0 .

The saml sso works fine to that point.
I really asume that some of you know what I have to change to get it running?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After in the Vaadin discord I was told to use the VaadinWebSecurity instead I had a tiny nervous breakdown. But then I had a look into that and with a tiny adaption to my spring security filter chain I got it running again.

From the VaadinWebSecurity. class I took

```
@Autowired
private RequestUtil requestUtil;
```

and changed my filter chain to

```
@Bean
SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http, MvcRequestMatcher.Builder mvc) throws Exception {

http.csrf().ignoringRequestMatchers(requestUtil::isFrameworkInternalRequest);

http.authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
.requestMatchers(mvc.pattern("/login"), mvc.pattern("/error"), mvc.pattern("/h2-console/**")).permitAll()
.anyRequest().authenticated()
).saml2Login(saml2 -> {
});
return http.build();
}
```

and now it is working again. Not very beautiful, as http.csrf() is again deprecated but I hope that this will do for at least a while.